# Can you dynamically extend a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In javascript you can do this:

```
function Test() {
  this.id = 1;
};

Test.prototype.customize = function(key, callback) {
  this[key] = callback;
};

var callback = function() { alert(this.id); };
var x = new Test();
x.customize('testing', callback);
x.testing();
```

Can you do a similar thing in typescript?

Particularly I'm interested in having a class like:

```
class Socket {
  ...
}

class Sockets {

  public addChannel(name:string):void {
    this[name] = new Socket(); 
  }

  ...
}

data = new Sockets();
data.addChannel('video');
data.addChannel('audio');

...

var audio = data.audio.read();
var video = data.video.read();
etc.
```

The compiler complains that there's no 'audio' or 'video' member on 'Sockets', and won't compile. Is there a way to work around that without having to manually define the properties on the container class?

I know it kind of side steps the static typing rules, but I find it occasionally useful for API niceness to have something like this.

edit: See the example answer I posted below; something like that works. I'll still accept any clever answer that lets me somehow manage to compile something that does something useful on the base object itself.

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible to statically verify.  (see the halting problem)

Comment: I know, but is there not some way I can something using a dictionary? Like public channels:{[name:string]:Socket} = {} ... data.channels.audio.read();. Does typescript always require that class properties and dictionary properties are read using [] brackets?

Comment: You can always write javascript if TS doesn't support it

Comment: For what you're trying to do, TypeScript is the wrong language to use. TypeScript *restricts* JavaScript, which means that not everything possible within JavaScript is possible in TypeScript, sometimes deliberately. For example, type-checking is a form of restriction -- you can assign a wrong type to a variable in JavaScript, but not TypeScript. Any language A that compiles down to language B is a restriction over the target language. What you're trying to do is something that TypeScript is *designed* to prevent.

Comment: TypeScript does not *restrict* JavaScript. It is a superset of JavaScript thus all valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript. The statement "Any language A that compiles down to language B is a restriction over the target language." is incorrect. It should instead say "...is retricted by the target language." TypeScript can't do anything (at runtime) that JavaScript can't do, but everything that is possible in JavaScript is possible in TypeScript. 
`var data: any = <unknown> new Sockets();` is allowed, just not advisable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update: It sounds like you are after truly dynamic behaviour at runtime... i.e. you don't know it will be `video`, `audio` or some other values. In this case, where you have a dynamic channel name from some source, you would have to use `[]` syntax - but there are still some

```
var channel = 'video;'

var data = new Sockets();
data.addChannel(channel);

// Totally dynamic / unchecked
var media = data[channel].read();

// Or

interface IChannel {
    read(): { /* You could type this */ };
}

// Dynamic call, but read method and media variable typed and checked
var media = (<IChannel>data[channel]).read();
```

---

Previous answer... useful for anyone reading this question who isn't after full on dynamic behaviour (but pretty useless for Doug, sorry!)

If you want to extend an existing class, you can use inheritance:

```
class ClassOne {
    addOne(input: number) {
        return input + 1;
    }
}

// ...

class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
    addTwo(input: number) {
        return input + 2;
    }
}

var classTwo = new ClassTwo();
var result = classTwo.addTwo(3); // 5
```

If you want to do this really dynamically, for example you just want to add something to an instance, you can do that too - but inheritance gives you much more for your money.

```
class ClassOne {
    addOne(input: number) {
        return input + 1;
    }
}

// ...

var classOne = new ClassOne();

classOne['addTwo'] = function (input: number) {
    return input + 2;
};

var result = (<any>classOne).addTwo(3); // 5

//or (nasty 'repeat the magic string version')

result = classOne['addTwo'](3);
```

If you are dead set on the dynamic route, a common pattern in TypeScript is to represent the structure with an interface, not a class. Interfaces (and modules, and enums) are open - so they can be extended over multiple blocks. You would need to ensure your interface and implementation were equally extended. This is the technique you use to extend built-in objects.

```
// NodeList is already declared in lib.d.ts - we are extending it
interface NodeList {
    sayNodeList(): void;
}

NodeList.prototype.sayNodeList = function () {
    alert('I say node, you say list... NODE');
}
```

This gives you full auto-completion and type checking.

Comment: Mm... I see what you're saying, but notice in the example question I do not 'before hand' know what the name of the channel I create is, so I can't define the interface (or extend the prototype) before hand; otherwise I could just create the class with static members and be done with it.

Comment: @Doug I see what you are saying. If you want truly dynamic behaviour, that is what TypeScript's `any` type is for - situations where you won't know the possible values at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

You're not extending the *type* in your example... you're just dynamically adding a property to the object. In TypeScript you can't dynamically add a property to an object containing properties with different types--unless you cast to `any` (which, in my opinion, should be avoided).

I would suggest adding a property to Sockets that is constrained to having properties who are of type `Socket` like so:

```
class Sockets {
    channels: { [index: string]: Socket; } = {};
    public addChannel(name:string):void {
        this.channels[name] = new Socket(); 
    }
}

var data = new Sockets();
data.addChannel('audio');

// audio will be the return type of read... so you don't lose type
var audio = data.channels['audio'].read();
```

By doing this you do not have to remember to cast the object to `Socket` and you get all the joys of type safety.

Comment: One point to note about this, is that although you have to write `data.channels['audio'].read()` in TypeScript (makes sense because typescript cannot verify `data.channels.audio`), in Javascript `data.channels.audio.read()` will work just fine when using the library.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Basic type
type a = {
  prop1: string
}

// Extended type
type b = a & {
  prop2: number
}

// Demo instance
let myExtendedObject: b = {
  prop1: 'text',
  prop2: 99
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible yet but there is an ongoing and active discussion occurring right now among the Typescript community.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blah {
  public channels:any = {};

  public addChan(name:string):void {
    this.channels[name] = new Channel();
  }
}

var b = new Blah();
b.channel('hello');
b.channels.hello.read(1024, () => { ... });
```

By default it seems any attribute of an 'any' time is also 'any', and you don't get any type safety in it without a cast, but if you're writing a typescript library to consume in javascript, it's not really a big deal.